# Imprimir valores primos contidos em um array

Tags: java

Não consigo pegar os números primos que estão dentro desse array List4; Já tentei várias formas, mas sem sucesso. Atualmente, meu código está assim:

```
List<Integer> list8 = new ArrayList<>();
    int numPrimo = 0;
            int numDivisores = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= list4.size(); i++) {
                if (numPrimo % i == 0) {
                    numDivisores++;
                }
                if(numDivisores == 2) {
                    list8.add(numDivisores);
                }
            }
            sysout("10) Os números primos entre as duas listas são: " + list8);
```

Preciso de uma luz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um for para listar todos os elementos da lista 4 e, dentro desse for, criar um novo laço para verificar se o número em questão é um número primo (incrementando a quantidade de divisores). Após esse segundo laço, você pode verificar se a quantidade de divisores é igual a 2, ou seja, se o número é primo. Segue o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list8 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list4.add(i);
    }

    int numDivisores = 0;

    for (Integer numPrimo : list4) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numPrimo; i++) {
            if (numPrimo % i == 0) {
                numDivisores++;
            }
        }

        if (numDivisores == 2) {
            list8.add(numPrimo);
        }
        numDivisores = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("10) Os números primos entre as duas listas são: " + list8);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu super certo e ainda me clareou uma dúvida maior!

Comment: Por nada, e que bom que te ajudou.